# Why AM-GM inequality showing different results?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I was given to find the minimum of $$1+a_1+a_2+a_3+...a_n$$. It was given that $$a_1\times{a_2}\times{a_3}...a_n =c$$
 My approach 
 
Using AM-GM inequality 
$1+a_1+a_2+...a_n\ge (n+1)c^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$

 
But the story doesn't ends here. There could be one more approach. 
$a_1+a_2+a_3+...a_n\ge nc^{\frac{1}{n}} $
So, $1+a_1+a_2+...a_n\ge 1+nc^{\frac{1} {n}} $

Both the approaches are giving different results. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Note where equality is allowed in AM-GM.  Is that compatible with your problem?

Comment: In the first case equality is allowed when all the terms in the numerator equals 1. In the second case it is allowed when all the terms are equal but not necessarily 1. So which of these is correct.?

Answer (score 6):

Both results are correct, but one of them tells you more than the other. For instance, if $x=20$, then both $x\ge10$ and $x\ge 5$ are correct, but $x\ge 10$ tells you more.

In your case, the second approach tells you more, because it uses explicitly the knowledge that the first term is equal to $1$. In fact, with a bit of work, you could even use this to prove that $1+nc^\frac{1}{n}\ge(n+1)c^\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Both results are correct, but they have different conditions for when the equality holds.

For the first inequality, the equality holds when $1 = a_1 = \cdots = a_n$.
But for the second inequality, the equality holds when $a_1=\cdots = a_n$.

As TonyK mentions above, the second inequality tells you more. The equality condition would constrain all the $a_i$s and causes $c = 1 (=a_1\dots a_n)$. But the second condition for the equality does not constrain any values for $c$.